# Laravel Relationship - One to Many Polymorphic

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Good evening stackers,

I am trying to understand how to make the following relationship in laravel, using models:

[image]

I want to be able to create a Classified that can be both a Car or a Motorcycle.

```
class Classified extends Model
{

    public function classified()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

```
class Car extends Model
{
    public function classified()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Classified::class, 'vehicle');
    }
}
```

My question here is: How can I **retrieve the vehicle information from the Classified**, using **relationships**?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `classified()` method to `vehicle()` (as type and id columns prefix):

```
class Classified extends Model
{

    public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
$classifieds = Classified::all();

foreach($classifieds as $classified){
    $classified->vehicle->name;
}
```

Creation:

```
$car->classified()->create([
    'name' => '...'
])

$motorcycle->classified()->create([
    'name' => '...'
])
```

Or similar action trough `Classified` model:

```
$classified = Classified::create([
    'vehicle_id' => $car->id,
    'vehicle_type' => $car->getMorphClass(),
    'name' => '...'
]);
```

Comment: @IndianConfig I appreciate the answer, if I may, can you please update your question with a create example?